# MYSQL: contar datos de otra tabla para insertar resultado en campo especifico

Tags: mysql

Una disculpa no supe como formular el titulo, pero de antemano muchas gracias para quienes me brinden la ayuda que necesito, el detalle es que tengo dos tablas una llamada usuariosservicios y otra tabla llamada carritorecibos ambas ocupan un campo llamado contrato donde se registran los datos en referencia al numero de contrato especifico de un usuario, lo que necesito saber es ¿Cómo contar la cantidad de recibos "VENCIDOS" de la tabla carritorecibos para obtener el resultado e ingresar ese resultado en el campo recibosVencidos (donde seria una actualización porque lo declare predeterminado en CERO) de la tabla usuariosservicios?

voy aprendiendo poco a poco ya google y busque dentro de Stackoverflow pero no eh encontrado algo parecido a lo que necesito, posiblemente por no saber formular la pregunta, se me hace fácil hacerlo por medio de consultas cargarlo en java y hacer las operaciones pero como son miles de registros no quiero ir de una por una seria tedioso, por eso necesito que me recorra todos los campos de acuerdo al campo contrato obteniendo las cantidades automáticamente e insertándolas en el campo actual para cuando imprima el recibo salga la cantidad de deudas de cada usuario, les agradecería mucho la ayuda prestada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UPDATE: siguiendo algunos post que eh encontrado de los poquitos por la red llegue a este update:

update usuariosservicio c
INNER JOIN (
SELECT contrato, sum(vR) AS total
from carritorecibos
GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total

Solo que despues de unos segundos me dice lo siguiente:

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1205 - Tiempo de bloqueo de espera excedido

Comment: Podrías agregar unas fotos de tus tablas para entender mejor la pregunta?

Comment: listo amigo represente mis tablas de esa manera porque las tablas son extensas y nada mas coloque los campos que podrían servir para identificar de que va cada tabla.

Comment: Al igual que @MiqueasGentile creo que deberías poner la estructura de tus tablas, bueno de los campos que son necesarios y agregar unos registros de ejemplo para poder entender con claridad el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos, ya iba a colocar la estructura pero encontré la solución ya la compartí en una respuesta, de todos modos muchas gracias por el interés prestado, saludos!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya logre lo que quería amigos, como todo buen programador contribuyo con la comunidad con la solución, en el post principal esta el mismo código solo que no me funciono porque posiblemente de tantas consultas que andaba probando y como son mas de 300,000 trescientos mil registros se tildo el server y por ello me salían esos mensajes descritos, posiblemente se soluciono con dos cosas:

Solución:
*hay que indexar los campos principales que se utilizan para realizar las consultas en este caso es el campo "contrato"

*posteriormente esta es la consulta que me funciono:

```
update usuariosservicio c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contrato, sum(vR) AS total 
    from carritorecibos
    GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total
```